# TicTacToe if statement not working for player 2

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm going to post the whole code so you can test yourself.
I don't get why the victory condition for player 2 is not triggered in the if statement.

I know that is cause the if statement, maybe I wrote it wrong but it is like 2 hours that I'm on it and I don't get what's wrong with the statement.
Works fine for player 1.

```
private static void ticTacToe()
{
    string[,] board = new string[3, 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
            board[i, j] = "-";
    string player1 = "X";
    string player2 = "O";
    string currentPlayer;
    int round = 1;
    int aX = 0;
    int aY = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    bool victory = false;
    while (flag == false || victory == false)
    {
        if (round == 1)
        {
            currentPlayer = player1;
            round++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPlayer = player2;
            round--;
        }

        bool valid = false;
        while (valid == false)
        {
            bool validCord = false;
            while (validCord == false)
            {
                Console.Write("Where to put(X Co)?: ");
                aX = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Where to put(Y Co)?: ");
                aY = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if(0 <= aX && aX <= 2 && 0 <= aY && aY <= 2)
                {
                    validCord = true;
                }
            }
            

            if (board[aY, aX] == "-")
            {
                valid = true;
                board[aY, aX] = currentPlayer;
            }

        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(board[i, j]);

                if (board[i, j] != "-")
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        //|||
        if ((board[0, 0] == "X" && board[1, 0] == "X" && board[2, 0] == "X") || (board[0, 0] == "Y" && board[1, 0] == "Y" && board[2, 0] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        else if ((board[0, 1] == "X" && board[1, 1] == "X" && board[2, 1] == "X") || (board[0, 1] == "Y" && board[1, 1] == "Y" && board[2, 1] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        else if ((board[0, 2] == "X" && board[1, 2] == "X" && board[2, 2] == "X") || (board[0, 2] == "Y" && board[1, 2] == "Y" && board[2, 2] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        //---
        else if ((board[0, 0] == "X" && board[0, 1] == "X" && board[0, 2] == "X") || (board[0, 0] == "Y" && board[0, 1] == "Y" && board[0, 2] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        else if ((board[1, 0] == "X" && board[1, 1] == "X" && board[1, 2] == "X") || (board[1, 0] == "Y" && board[1, 1] == "Y" && board[1, 2] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        else if ((board[2, 0] == "X" && board[2, 1] == "X" && board[2, 2] == "X") || (board[2, 0] == "Y" && board[2, 1] == "Y" && board[2, 2] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        //X
        else if ((board[0, 0] == "X" && board[1, 1] == "X" && board[2, 2] == "X") || (board[0, 0] == "Y" && board[1, 1] == "Y" && board[2, 2] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
        else if ((board[0, 2] == "X" && board[1, 1] == "X" && board[2, 0] == "X") || (board[0, 2] == "Y" && board[1, 1] == "Y" && board[2, 0] == "Y"))
        {
            victory = true;
            Console.Write(victory + " Victory for player " + currentPlayer);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Well, you are comparing the contents of the board to `Y` but you place `O` for player 2. Instead of comparing to `X` and `O` you could also simply check `if (board[0,0] == currentPlayer ...)` so you won'T have to duplicate every winning situation for both players ... Because a winning situation can always occur for the player who placed a mark

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug code using the **[free, awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: I'm so stupid, lol, too much work, never relax coding. @derpirscher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your code, you have these definitions for `player1` and `player2`:

```
string player1 = "X";
string player2 = "O";
```

However, all of your `if` statements look like this:

```
if ((board[0, 0] == "X" && board[1, 0] == "X" && board[2, 0] == "X") || (board[0, 0] == "Y" && board[1, 0] == "Y" && board[2, 0] == "Y"))
```

You're checking for `X` and `Y` instead of `X` and `O`, hence why the win condition is never triggered for `player2`.

Comment: I'm so stupid, lol, too much work, never relax coding.

Comment: You're not stupid, just treat it as a learning opportunity. Also I know this wasn't the point of your question, but when you've got so much repeated code like this, it's a great opportunity to simplify and condense it. You could do something like define each set of three coordinates that constitute a consecutive sequence (like "0,0", "0,1", "0,2"), then loop through those sets and see if all the values equal `player1` or `player2`. When there's a lot of code like this, there are lots of places for subtle bugs to hide.